# What does text != "" mean?

Tags: javascript, string, while-loop

This is from chapter 6 in Eloquent Javascript:

**Code:**

```
 function splitParagraph(text) {
     var fragments = []; 
     while( text != "" )                         // ?
         if (text.charAt(0) == "*") {
               fragments.push({type: "emphasized"});

 etc...
```

I am having trouble grasping what the while loop is doing. *Text* is a string. Does the while loop read "while text doesn't have any characters remaining.." Is the while loop looking at every character in the string one by one making sure there is another character left?

Comment: Far from eloquent if that is copied directly (is it, or is there something omitted?). Its itching to be an infinite loop and a stack overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `while` loop keeps running while the condition inside is true. In this case, `text != ""` is true if the string in question is not an empty string.

In this particular case, I guess `text` must be changed somewhere inside the loop, otherwise it doesn't make sense to use a `while` construct here.

**NOTE**: Actually, in JavaScript, the `!=` and `==` operators will evaluate in a pretty curious way: 0, `[]` and `""`, for instance, will all be considered equal:

- `"" != []` -> false
- `0 != []` -> false
- `0 != ""` -> false

`===` and `!==` can be used to enforce strict equality.

Comment: !== and === are also faster.

Comment: Great advice. Should I always use `!==` and `===` over `!=` and `==`

Comment: Well, non-strict operators have their use too. For instance, `2 == '2'` but `2 !== '2'`.

Answer (score 1):

It checks if text isn't an empty string (length 0 and containing no characters).

Comment: In this particular case, the while loop iterates as long as `text` is not length 0 (empty).. then it will check if the first character of text is "*"?

Answer (score 1):

```
"Is the while loop looking at every character in the string 
one by one making sure there is another character left?"
```

Yes though the entire loop is not shown that is almost certainly what is being done.

The while condition checks if the `text` string is empty.
If not empty, the loop iterates through the body of the loop.
The `text.charAt(0)` checks the first character of the string. If a '*' character is found, 
an element is added to the `fragments` array.

Within the body there will be code to remove the first character of the `text` string 
and the loop then processes the next character of the string.

```
while( text != "" )                        
         if (text.charAt(0) == "*") {
               fragments.push({type: "emphasized"});
```

Answer (score 0):

> What does text != “” mean?

It means if the value of `text` can not be coerced to match `""`

consider this code

```
if ("abc" != "") {
    console.log("1 ok");
}

if ([] != "") {
    console.log("2 ok");
}

if (0 != "") {
    console.log("3 ok");
}

if (false != "") {
    console.log("4 ok");
}
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/2Cr7g/)

Oh dear, what happened in case 2 and 3 and 4?